# Url length limit of addFileAttachmentAsync in Outlook

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We make use of the addFileAttachmentAsync method in our add-in.

The allowed max URL length seems to have changed in a recent Outlook 2016 update, we are seeing any URL over +-260 characters failing to attach.
The documentation states that 2048 characters are allowed.

In older builds of Outlook 2016 (16.0.6868.xxxx) this works fine as per the documentation.

The returned result object in the call back has "status" set to "succeeded" and value "4". But the file is not correctly attached, the attached item in the mail says "Download failed".

An example URL is: https://acmestestabc-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/contentsources/bec3f0fc-6344-e711-80c2-000d3a22ae5a/files/bytes?accessToken=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&fileId=eyJJc0xpc3QiOmZhbHNlLCJGaWxlR3VpZCI6Ins0MEYxxkJGMS1GMTk2LTQwRTktQUVFNS05MEE1MzIzNEUyOUF9IiwiRm9sZGVyR3VpZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3BlMjAyNTkxLnNoYXJlcG9pbnQuY29tL3NpdGVzL2hlbm5pZS9TaGFyZWQgRG9jdW1lbnRzL1BoYXJtYWN5LmRvY3giLCJTaXRlVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zcGUyMDI1OTEuc2hhcmVwb2ludC5jb20vc2l0ZXMvaGVubmllIiwiUGFyZW50SWQiOn51bGx90